# voronoi_plot_2d in SciPy, difference between dashed lines and solid lines? and warning?

Tags: python, scipy, voronoi

So I was using the function voronoi_plot_2d() which is part of SciPy and when I plot my diagram, I got the diagram below, where some have solid borders between the clusters and some have dashed borders. (The scatter plot of each cluster is hidden)

Do they have separate meaning behind them? If they are the same thing, how can I specify that I only want to plot solid borders, for example? The documentation (http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.spatial.voronoi_plot_2d.html) does not mention anything.

[image]

Also, I got the following warning

```
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The ishold function was deprecated in version 2.0.
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: axes.hold is deprecated.
```

when I use the voronoi_plot_2d() function. I'm running Python 3.5, is there a way to make the warning disappear? I don't use either the ishold function or axes.hold in my code, so the warning must've come from inside the voronoi_plot_2d().

Comment: As a wild guess the dashed lines extends indefinitely (so the cell is  infinite)

Comment: @6502 Ahhh, that actually makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: By having a look at the source code one can verify that 6502s guess was correct: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/1c7d7fc04315071ea2fc6c991cf470ad6e637ec3/scipy/spatial/_plotutils.py#L199

@6502 you may convert your comment to an answer

Answer (score 4):

Dashed lines are infinite and are used when the Voronoi cell is infinite.